# Errors in Tesseract integration in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, tesseract

I am getting some errors while integrating Tesseract SDK in my iOS app. 
The procedure I have followed  -

1) Dragged "libtesseract_full.a" in xcode
2) Dragged "tessdata" folder in xcode
3) Dragged "baseapi.h" in xcode

Now when I am using Tesseract -

```
// init the tesseract engine.
tess = new TessBaseAPI();

tess->SimpleInit([dataPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],  // Path to tessdata-no ending /.
                 "eng",  // ISO 639-3 string or NULL.
                 false);
```

I am getting these below errors (I think there is some framework or something like that missing, but not getting what is missing, tesseract demo project is working fine on my system)

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdc++'
ld: warning: CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_ALL subtype is deprecated: /Users/saurabhsharma/Desktop/Tess/SnapXv2/libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      SVNetwork::SVNetwork(char const*, int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_decrement(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<char const* const, int> >::operator--() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, VariableContent*> >::operator--() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > >::operator--() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> >::operator--() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::string::operator+=(char const*)", referenced from:
      ScrollView::SendPolygon() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::string::size() const", referenced from:
      SVNetwork::Flush() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::string::erase(unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      SVNetwork::Flush() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, ScrollView*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> >) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType>, std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > >, std::less<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > > >::erase(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > >) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::string::length() const", referenced from:
      SVNetwork::Flush() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::string::operator+=(char)", referenced from:
      ScrollView::SendPolygon() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      ScrollView::SendPolygon() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      SVNetwork::SVNetwork(char const*, int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, VariableContent*> >::operator++() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<char const* const, int> >::operator++() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> >::operator++() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > >::operator++() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> >::operator++(int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > >::operator++(int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)", referenced from:
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, VariableContent*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, VariableContent*> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, VariableContent*> > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<int const, VariableContent*> const&) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<char const*, std::pair<char const* const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<char const* const, int> >, std::less<char const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<char const* const, int> > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<char const* const, int> const&) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, ScrollView*>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<int const, ScrollView*> const&) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      std::_Rb_tree<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType>, std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> >, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > >, std::less<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > > >::_M_insert(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::pair<std::pair<ScrollView*, SVEventType> const, std::pair<SVSemaphore*, SVEvent*> > const&) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      ___tcf_0 in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
      ScrollView::SendPolygon() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      SVNetwork::Flush() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()", referenced from:
      ScrollView::SendPolygon() in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
      SVNetwork::SVNetwork(char const*, int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::string::append(char const*)", referenced from:
      SVNetwork::Send(char const*) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      SVNetwork::SVNetwork(char const*, int) in libtesseract_full.a(libtesseract_full.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The C++ standard library is not being linked against.

Comment: I have added "-stdc++" and "-ObjC" in other linker flag.

Comment: it should be `-lstdc++`.

Comment: just added "-lstdc++" but its not working..

Comment: Try linking using `clang++` instead of `clang` maybe. (Without seeing the actual project, is hard to guess blind, sorry.)

Comment: the demo project have "-stdc++" in other linker flag and its working.. I think there is something more missing.. thoughts?

Comment: just changed "C++ Standard Library" in build settings to "libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library) and errors are gone… Thanks H2CO3… love you!

Comment: My case I have to use "libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)."

Comment: I have added "-stdc++",  "-ObjC", "-lz" in other linker flag. Please check the Template Framework Project settings

Answer (score 20, accepted):

just changed "C++ Standard Library" in build settings to "libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library)" and errors are gone… Thanks @H2CO3 for hint.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

Firstly ensure the file containing the code:

```
tess = new TessBaseAPI();
tess->SimpleInit(...);
```

has a file extension of `.mm` (Objective-C++) as it uses both Objective-C and C++.

Secondly the library looks like it hasn't been compiled for `armv7`, so you will need to rebuild it for any architectures you want to support, which will be one or more of `armv6`, `armv7`, `armv7s` and `i386` (for the iPhone Simulator).

If you are targeting iOS 5.0+ then that will be all of the above apart from `armv6` which isn't supported on later versions of Xcode.

Thirdly, make sure you use the same version of C++ and C++ library in both the library and the app, otherwise bad things will happen.

Comment: just changed "C++ Standard Library" in build settings to "libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library) and errors are gone… Thanks @H2CO3

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

C++ Language Dialect Set "Compiler Default"  instead of "GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]"

C++ Standard Library Set "Compiler Default" instead of "libc++(LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)"

Also check:

C Language Dialect Set "C00 [-std=c99]" instead of "GNU00 [-std=gnu99]"

and tesseract files should be referenced properly. (drag and drop files not reference properly)

Answer (score 0):

```
ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

1. Change Project -> Project -> Build Settings -> **"Enable Bitcode"
   to NO
2. also remove all linker flags in "linking" -> "Other Linker Flags"
   and add this

[image: Linker Flags]
 3. After that install pods by command "pod install"

It's works for me on Swift 2 and Xcode 7.2 (beta)